# Cannot import package after successfully installed

Tags: python, miniconda

**Environment**:

- PyCharm
- Python interpreter: Conda, Python 3.7.15

I tried to install a package from github (git+https:// ...) in the exact interpreter. I did check File -> Setting -> Project -> Python Interpreter. The package name appeared in the list of installed packages. (Let's say the name is `abc`).

However when I tried to import it like `import abc`, `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'abc'` shows up. How can I solve this?

Comment: The package name given in the setup file of the package is not always the same as the name(s) of the python modules that are defined in the package. Example is `PyYAML`, defining a module called `yaml`. BTW: If your package is `abc`, it may clash with the standard abstract class module with exactly that name :-D.

Comment: @Dr.V Is there anyway I can find the correct name to import?

Comment: If it's a public repo, it is hopefully documented with examples. If not, you must analyse the package's `setup.py` file (in root folder) and/or the folder structure of the project. If the project folder contains a `src` directory, the module names are likely the names of the directories in there.

Comment: @Dr.V in the `setup.py` file, it specifies `py_modules=['abc']` and `name='abc'`. I'm not sure if there is anythong wrong ...

Comment: It's difficult to propose something general. You can confirm also from a terminal via `pip list`, whether it's there. Then you can find the `site-packages` folder in your environment (close to where the actual `python.exe` resides.

Comment: @Dr.V it does appears with the exact same name in `pip list`, however in `site-packages` it looks like `abc-x.x.x.dist-info`

Comment: If there is no folder `abc`, then that is the problem. Well again. If it is a public repository, why don't you share the actual name? And if it is private, you must know the developer, who should be able to give specific advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a private repo and doesn't follow rules of setuptools, so after built and installed, only subpackages are visible.